# Extra quotes from exporting from SQL Server to CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, openrowset

I am getting extra double quotes (") when exporting to CSV using "Insert into OpenRowSet" command from a SQL Server stored procedure (this is part of a C# Visual Studio Core2 automation program, so I need this to run without any intervention.)

When I run:

```
SELECT data1 as DeleteThisLine  
FROM tmpExportData
```

I get the following results:

```
DeleteThisLine
-----------------------------------------------------
"@HDR","@BATCH",20190611,Date Range: 06/11-06/19/2019
"@HDR","JOURNAL",,
```

If I right click and save as .csv, the resulting file looks exactly like the above results.

However when I run the "INSERT INTO OPENROWSET" command to export the results into a csv file:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=\\FileSever229\file\;HDR=YES;H=-1;FMT=Delimited','SELECT * FROM [ExportFile_06_24_120522.csv]')
    SELECT data1 AS DeleteThisLine 
    FROM tmpExportData
```

It exports the file, but with Extra double quotes at the beginning and end of every line and double quotes around the first 2 fields:

```
DeleteThisLine
-----------------------------------------------------------
"""@HDR"",""@BATCH"",20190611,Date Range: 06/11-06/19/2019"
"""@HDR"",""JOURNAL"",,"
```

How do I eliminate these extra quotes?

Background:

This is an unusual situation where I am creating a Batch file that is to be uploaded into an accounting system. It holds all that information in a single cell (data1) as each row in the upload file has a different number of columns and each row has a set of variables of different types. So all the data is in a single column. It was working great, and then these extra quotes appeared. I must have changed something in my "insert into OPENROWSET" command.

Comment: There's *NO* way you'd get the first result with `SELECT data1 as DeleteThisLine FROM tmpExportData` unless `data1` already contained those quotes. In which case, the first result isn't a correct, single-column CSV output.  The *second* result is probably the *correct* one as far as CSV is concerned.

Comment: How did `data1` end up containing what looks to be multiple columns? If you want to export query results as CSV there are simple ways to do so correctly, eg a `bcp` command or the `OPENROWSET` command used with a proper query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is an unusual situation where I am creating a file that is to be uploaded into an accounting system and yes, it holds all that information in a single cell as each row has a different number of columns and each row has a set of variables of different types. So all the data is in a single column. It was working great, and then these extra quotes appeared. I must have changed something in my "insert into OPENROWSET" command.

Comment: On the contrary, `OPENROWSET` works as it should. The cell contains double quotes, so it *has* to be text delimited. The problem is that you aren't trying to export data to CSV, you're trying to export already formatted text *without* formatting it again. *Don't* use OPENROWSET in that case.

Comment: In fact, why don't you use any of the *built-in* mechanisms for exporting to CSV, like `bcp` or SSIS? Or any library that exports to CSV in your language of choice?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I was making this harder. Post the bcp option as the solution and I will give it a big check mark! Thanks!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, as Op said he has data with variable number of columns ("each row has a different number of columns"). Built in SQL tools cannot handle these scenarios.

Comment: @Alex that's exactly what they *can* do. They can export any query result

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I can't argue .... against blanket statements.

Comment: @Alex isn't that what you did? SSIS, bcp, sqlcmd all work with queries, or table/view names. If by `variable columns` you mean rows with a different number of fields in the same query, well, that's impossible with SQL, the language, not just SQL Server. A query can't return different columns for each row. If you want to export multiple queries to the same file a) that's not a CSV any more, it's a report b) It's still possible with sqlcmd and SSIS and c) there are better tools for reporting

Comment: @Alex  - I added that content about the single column because Panagiotis  asked that question. In other words, that info wasn't there when he asked the question. And I have solved this using BCP so problem solved and thank you very much! For the record, Panagiotis is correct, you can export anything with a query result... That's the beauty of T-SQL. (If Panagiotis posts the BCP as a solution I will give credit where credit is due. Thanks again.